# SQL query fails in EF Core

Tags: sql, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a method in the repository (EF Core) that should produce a complex request to the database:

```
public Task<List<Invoice>> GetOrderedVInvoicesAsync(string email, string lang, int rows, int offset)
        {           
           return _contex.VInvoice.FromSqlInterpolated($"SELECT DocumentNumber,DocumentDate,DocumentReference,SerialNumber,ProductCode,Description,Certificate FROM vInvoice WHERE CHECKSUM(DocumentNumber + DocumentReference + CAST(DocumentDate AS VARCHAR)) IN (SELECT CHECKSUM(DocumentNumber + DocumentReference + CAST(DocumentDate AS VARCHAR)) FROM vInvoice WHERE Email={email} AND Language={lang} GROUP BY DocumentNumber,DocumentDate,DocumentReference ORDER BY DocumentDate OFFSET {offset} ROWS FETCH NEXT {rows} ROWS ONLY)").ToListAsync();
        }
```

But he gives me an error

> The required column 'Email' was not present in the results of a
>   'FromSql' operation.

Tell me where I was wrong

Comment: Your `SELECT` statement doesn't include `Email`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, There further on request there is a nested `select`. The fact is that in `ManagmentStudio` this query works.

Comment: Yes, but this isn't Management Studio.

Comment: Looks like `VInvoice.FromSqlInterpolated` tries to map the result back to the model `Invoice`. If this type has a required property `Email` then it must also be included in the result set that is being mapped back to that type. That is what the error is stating.

Comment: your method return result must completely be like `Invoice` object. that in your query seems it is not. (WHY?). I guess you have a property of `Email` in `Invoice` object but in your `SELECT` you didn't fetch `Email` column. so it's logical that it raises an error.